# Parallel Maven Assembly Executions

Tags: java, maven, parallel-processing, continuous-integration

Part of my build creates environment-specific zips for each of my 15 environments. I'm using the maven-assembly-plugin and am looking for a way to parallelise each execution so I can save a few minutes on the build time.

Specifically, this isn't parallel maven builds, which builds individual projects in parallel, but parallel executions of a plugin within a single project build.

Comment: Are all those creations of zips defined within a single module (pom.xml) ? Are you using different descriptors ? And how long does it take to create all of those zip's ? What is the size of the resulting zip's ?

Comment: Single module. 2 different descriptors per execution, 1 for a jar, 1 for a zip.  resulting Zips/jars are ~2meg and take approx 5 seconds each due to number of files being filtered.

Comment: So you have talked about a few minutes? If i calculate correct 2 descriptors * 5 second ? I don't minutes here ?

Comment: You haven't calculated correctly. 15 environments * 2 descriptors * 5 seconds = 150 seconds = 2 minutes, 30 seconds.

Comment: I assumed that i've calculated wrong...So you have several executions ? Can you show an example how your pom file looks like ? Is this module part of a multi module build? Where are those environment specific parts located etc. ? An example how it looks like would be helpful.